# How to judge whether a class or an object is singleton or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I wrote a class method like this:

```
Class class;

BOOL isSingleton = [class isSingleton];
```

But I have no idea how to implement the class method `+ isSingleton`
How to know whether a *class or a object is a singleton or not*?

Comment: I would suggest to create two instances (within the isSingleton method) of the singleton class using whatever initialiser u have created. then compare the two instances. if they are same.. Return YES. But what is your purpose to do so ?

Comment: I think that having to test for singleton-ness at runtime is an indicator of not so good design. Maybe rethink if you really need to use a singleton here or if some other construct would better serve your purpose

Comment: It is definitely an interesting question what you would do with this information if you had it. Usually I can guess something, but nothing is coming to mind. Something related to serialization? (Not that you'd need it for that; I'm just trying to guess.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is add a category named "NSObject+Singleton.h" to NSObject, then add a class method `+ isSingleton` inside.
Thus I can decide that a class is singleton or not by myself, as long as override the isSingleton method in subclass and return YES or NO.
Then if I want to know a instance of a class is singleton or not, just invoke `[[object class] isSingleton]`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. Singletons do not have "singleton-ness" to test for. They are just regular objects that there happens to only be one of.

Comment: And sometimes there may even more than one. :D i.e. many things that have a "sharedFoo" "singleton."